# Передача из данных из одного конструктора класса к другому конструктору другого класса

Tags: c++

Есть класс CStep1{}, в котором есть конструктор, где находятся 6 косинусов

```
class CStep1 {
public: 
CStep1(double f_azimut_E1, double f_azimut_B1, double f_azimut_E2, double f_azimut_B2){ 
    double cos_ax = cos(f_azimut_E1)*cos(f_azimut_B1);
    double cos_ay = cos(f_azimut_E1)*sin(f_azimut_B1); 
    double cos_ah = sin(f_azimut_E1);

    double cos_bx = cos(f_azimut_E2)*cos(f_azimut_B2);
    double cos_by = cos(f_azimut_E2)*sin(f_azimut_B2);
    double cos_bh = sin(f_azimut_E2);
}
```

Также есть класс CStep2, в котором тоже есть конструктор и в нем есть переменные(а1, a2, a3...). Мне нужно передать косинусы из CStep1 в CStep2

```
class CStep2{   
public:
CStep2(){
    double a1 = cos_ah*cos_bx-cos_ax*cos_bh;
    double a2 = cos_ay*cos_bh-cos_ah*cos_by;
    double a3 = cos_ax*cos_by-cos_ay*cos_bx;
    double b1 = cos_ax*(h2-h1)-cos_ah*(x2-x1);
    double b2 = cos_ah*(y2-y1)-cos_ay*(h2-h1);
    double b3 = cos_ay*(x2-x1)-cos_ax*(y2-y1);
}
```

Comment: По-моему, я уже болел этим дежавю... Ну сохраните их в объекте `CStep1`, и передайте этот объект в конструктор `CStep2`...

Comment: сохранить в структуру `struct Cos{double cos_ax;... };` , и передать её как аргумент в конструктор `CStep2(Cos sc){sc.cos_ax ..}`